# Flutter web app deployed to Firebase crashes when trying to play mp3 music file

Tags: flutter, firebase-hosting, just-audio

I have a Flutter web app that is using the 'just_audio' package.

Everything works fine when running locally  After I deploy this to Firebase,  when I run the same feature the web app throws the following error when it tries to play a 'mp3' jusic file.

```
Uncaught MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method disposeAllPlayers on channel com.ryanheise.just_audio.methods)
    at Object.d (https://eisgd.com/main.dart.js:5248:3)
    at https://eisgd.com/main.dart.js:111603:15
    at c3Q.a (https://eisgd.com/main.dart.js:6614:62)
    at c3Q.$2 (https://eisgd.com/main.dart.js:68919:14)
    at c27.$1 (https://eisgd.com/main.dart.js:68913:21)
    at aGc.bqp (https://eisgd.com/main.dart.js:70063:34)
    at aGc.Ir (https://eisgd.com/main.dart.js:70065:21)
    at bFs.$0 (https://eisgd.com/main.dart.js:69342:11)
    at Object.T1 (https://eisgd.com/main.dart.js:6748:40)
    at aG.we (https://eisgd.com/main.dart.js:69275:3)
d @ main.dart.js:5248
cEn @ main.dart.js:7902
cbJ @ main.dart.js:8024
$0 @ main.dart.js:70035
cRm @ main.dart.js:6780
cRM @ main.dart.js:6782
$1 @ main.dart.js:68863
cUG @ main.dart.js:5329
(anonymous) @ main.dart.js:5337
childList (async)
$1 @ main.dart.js:68870
csv @ main.dart.js:6787
FO @ main.dart.js:6883
a8i @ main.dart.js:69282
ne @ main.dart.js:69280
fw @ main.dart.js:6666
(anonymous) @ main.dart.js:16065
(anonymous) @ main.dart.js:6614
$2 @ main.dart.js:68919
o @ main.dart.js:6600
ajW @ main.dart.js:16068
Q_ @ main.dart.js:88806
(anonymous) @ main.dart.js:5369
aoB @ main.dart.js:83044
fC @ main.dart.js:83048
anQ @ main.dart.js:83208
a9I @ main.dart.js:83179
anN @ main.dart.js:83142
l1 @ main.dart.js:83106
(anonymous) @ main.dart.js:5370
aLE @ main.dart.js:83002
$2 @ main.dart.js:83014
av @ main.dart.js:68364
aaG @ main.dart.js:83009
arD @ main.dart.js:83007
mF @ main.dart.js:81992
a0j @ main.dart.js:81986
a0j @ main.dart.js:114490
acU @ main.dart.js:81980
a1g @ main.dart.js:81969
Wd @ main.dart.js:81967
aU9 @ main.dart.js:81960
(anonymous) @ main.dart.js:5370
aMn @ main.dart.js:1933
aZP @ main.dart.js:62767
(anonymous) @ main.dart.js:5370
$1 @ main.dart.js:63032
$1 @ main.dart.js:62986
$1 @ main.dart.js:62778
cnN @ main.dart.js:5204
akJ @ main.dart.js:7892
cPX @ main.dart.js:9426
(anonymous) @ main.dart.js:9422
```

The error is related to playing a 'mp3' music file. Something else I found a suggestion that this is to do with the web app not having been defined to support 'mp3' media files.

However, I can't find anywhere to configure mp3 support. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

A response on the Firebase Slack channel advised that Firebase hosting does NOT support audio streaming.

This seems like a bizarre limitation, and effectively kills Firebase as a hosting option for me.